# QGraphicsView paint not called

Tags: qt, tree, paint, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsscene

I'm working on a tree view for a user-defined class called Family_tree with nodes having a pointer to their father, mother, spouse and a vector of children. I created a TreeViewNode class derived from QGraphicsItem with a node* m_node member and overrides for the boundingRect and paint methods like so:

```
QRectF TreeViewNode::boundingRect() const {
    return QRectF(-50, -50, 100, 100);
}

void TreeViewNode::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget) {
    qDebug() << "Paint function called";
    painter->drawRect(boundingRect());
    painter->drawText(boundingRect(), Qt::AlignCenter, QString::fromStdString(m_node->getPatient().get_Name()));

    for (auto child : m_node->getChildren()) {
        TreeViewNode* childNode = new TreeViewNode(child, this);
        childNode->setPos(0, 100);
        QLineF line(0, 50, 0, 150);
        painter->drawLine(line);
    }
}
```

I've set up a Family_tree with just one node for simplicity (the root) and I'm trying to get it to show in the view in MainWindow but I don't see paint getting called at all despite me adding the root to the scene (scene.item().count() returns 1..) and the view is simply blank. Am I doing something blatantly wrong here? Thank you for your time!

```
//MainWindow.cpp
TreeViewNode* root = new TreeViewNode(family->get_root());
view = new QGraphicsView(); QGraphicsScene scene; view->setScene(&scene);
scene.addItem(root); root->setPos(100, 100); view->update();
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].  The code shown creates a `QGraphicsView` with no parent meaning it's a top-level window, but never calls `QWidget::show()` on it.  Also, if the code shown is in your `MainWindow` constructor, `scene` will be destroyed as soon as it goes out of scope when the constructor finishes.

Comment: thank you so much, the issue was indeed the scene being local to the MainWindow constructor.